# Python math module not able to calculate

Tags: python, math

I am writing a little python script and have run into a problem.

```
Comma_shift = 503559669306.1
Simpdays = (Comma_shift - math.floor(Comma_shift))*10
```

This should give me 1, but it gives me 0 for `Simpdays`. If `Comma_shift` is equal to `503559669306.2` I get 2, as expected. What am I doing wrong? Is there some rounding involved that I am not aware of?

Thank you!

Comment: What's the output of `print(type(Comma_shift), repr(Comma_shift), Comma_shift.__sizeof__())`?

Answer (score 0):

The value of `Simpdays` comes out to be `0.999755859375` so yes, I do think the value is being rounded.

Comment: Why would that be?

Comment: Are you printing the value?